# Segmentation fault during erasing from vector

Tags: c++, vector, erase, fault

I'm developing an Asteroid game clone but I'm facing a problem during erasing elements from vector of asteroids. So generally when I hit the asteroid it should split into 3 parts. So I create 3 new asteroids and erase the old one an then it crashes.

```
void Level::missleAsteroidCollision(){
    std::cout<<this->asteroidVector.size()<<std::endl;
    for(auto ptr = this->missleVector.begin();ptr!=this->missleVector.end();++ptr){
            sf::FloatRect missleBounds = (*ptr)->shape.getGlobalBounds();
            for(auto ptrTwo = this->asteroidVector.begin(); ptrTwo!= this->asteroidVector.end();++ptrTwo){
                if(missleBounds.intersects((*ptrTwo)->shape.getBounds()) && (*ptrTwo)->isFinalForm == false){
                    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                        this->createAsteroid((*ptrTwo)->origin,true);
                    }
                    delete *ptrTwo;
                    this->asteroidVector.erase(ptrTwo);
                }
                else if(missleBounds.intersects((*ptrTwo)->shape.getBounds()) && (*ptrTwo)->isFinalForm == true){
                    delete *ptrTwo;
                    this->asteroidVector.erase(ptrTwo);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and finally, provide a [mcve].

Comment: erase() invalidates iterators, use remove/erase idiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you use the .erease function, the iterator is changed so you need to update it, in your case, `ptr = this->asteroidVector.erase(ptrTwo);` the iterator will now point to the next element after deletion so keep that in mind (either you decrease the pointer by one or you only increase the ptr (ptr++) if you did not use the .erase function.

Secondly, I believe `this->createAsteroid((*ptrTwo)->origin,true);` creates new items, this will also invalidate the iterator, so one fix could be, creating the new asteroids after checking and deleting the old one. Maybe store the new asteroids in a vector created before the for loop, adding the new meteorites there and after the for loop add the vector to your current vector of asteroids.

Comment: Another alternative is to iterate backwards. Only iterators at or after the erased element are invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an item into a vector (whether or not at the end of the vector) can invalidate all iterators to that vector. I suspect your createAsteroid does so.

Comment: Yes, createAsteroid() pushes new object to asteroidVector. Any suggestions how to deal with this problem?